# How to support Facebook SDK 3.1 on iOS SDK 5.1?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

The main purpose of the Facebook SDK 3.1 is to bring compatibility with iOS v6.0 and its native Facebook support.

There are no AdSupport and social frameworks in ios 5(i am working on xcode 4.3.2 iphone 5.1 simulator), Can we download these frameworks or is there an other way to run without these frameworks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/features/whats-new-ios-sdk-3.1/):

> Seamless Facebook Login across iOS versions: Lets your app work
>   seamlessly on all iOS versions 4.0+ and easily integrates with the
>   native login support in iOS 6.

In the Getting Started with the Facebook SDK 3.1, when it says to add the Accounts, Social and AdSupport frameworks to your "link binary with libraries" don't forget to change Required to Optional on the right of the panel for those 3 frameworks.

This way you can support from iOS 4.* to iOS 6.